# Python https connection using self-signed cert

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, adfs

I'm trying to implement SSL from inside a python script.  I've obtained the cert by browsing to the page, and accepting the self-signed cert.  Then I've exported it from Firefox, and saved it as a .pem to my desktop.

The code is:

```
sslcertlocation = '/Users/derjur/Desktop/MYHOST.mydomain.local.pem'

idpentryurl = 'https://MYHOST.mydomain.local:443/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=urn:amazon:webservices'

session = requests.Session()

response = session.get(idpentryurl, verify=sslcertlocation)
```

The error is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

MYHOST is running iis7 under Windows 2008 R2.  The complete script is based on the SAML/ADFS script as described in this blog:
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1LDN0UBGJJ26Q/How-to-Implement-Federated-API-and-CLI-Access-Using-SAML-2-0-and-AD-FS#postCommentsTx1LDN0UBGJJ26Q

The non-SSL portions of the script are working as expected.  Interestingly, no one in the comments mentions SSL...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're setting the wrong argument. According to requests.Session(), get() sends the optional argument of verify - a boolean - to request().

According to request.Session().request(), the parameter to pass your certificate in is cert=/path/to/cert.pem, which is also checked as a string being a path or a tuple being a (cert, key) pair.

Comment: I've modified the line to `response = session.get(idpentryurl, cert=sslcertlocation)` and the error has changed to `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2600)`.  Is it possible that I'm using the wrong type of cert?

Comment: Converting to a .crt (with `openssl x509 -outform der -in MYHOST.mydomain.local.pem -out MYHOST.mydomain.local.crt` ) changed the error to `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2581)`